# Broadcom Wireless Network problem on Kubuntu LTS 16.04.02

Tags: networking, wireless, kubuntu, internet, broadcom

I am conscious of the fact that this question has been asked and solved *multiple times*, but I've never found a working solution to my problem, so I'd ask this wonderful community to be clement and merciful towards me.

As the title states, I'm having some trouble getting my WiFi working. Some days ago I've installed Kubuntu 16.04.02 LTS on an Acer Aspire E5-571 but since the first time I booted, my network manager does not show any wireless network available. I've learnt that Broadcom has proved itself to be very troublesome with Ubuntu, so the first thing I did was checking if this was my case: affirmative.

OUTPUT of the command line `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [11ad:6645]
```

Someone was suggesting to install Ndiswrapper, so I tried following step by step [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Drive/Ndiswrapper) but during the installation of the ndisgtk package this error showed up:

OUTPUT of the command line `sudo apt-get install ndisgtk`

```
[...]    
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.8.0-36-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/ndiswrapper/1.59/build/make.log for more information.
```

Others said that this kind of problem was due to Safe Boot Mode being on, and in fact it was enabled (which also caused my HDD's status to be FROZEN (?) when checking in F2 Boot Menu). I disabled it (which made my HDD to be set back to CLEAR), but it hasn't solved anything as far as Wireless Network is concerned.

I've re-installed Kubuntu multiple times (also tried with Ubuntu and Lubuntu, giving the same problem), hoping to be lucky enough, but it wasn't the case. I've (obviously) tried to press the Wireless Switch on my keyboard to see if it could be off, but nope.

Additional Infos

OUTPUT of the command line `rfkill list`

```
1: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
2: acer-bluetooth: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

OUTPUT of the command line `lshw -C network`

```
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0.1
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.1
       logical name: enp1s0f1
       version: 12
       serial: f0:76:1c:79:4c:45
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8411-2_0.0.1 07/08/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:45 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b0504000-b0504fff memory:b0500000-b0503fff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:b0400000-b0407fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: enp0s20u3
       serial: a2:50:49:44:ed:bd
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.146 link=yes multicast=yes
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
```

OUTPUT of the command line `iwconfig`

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp1s0f1  no wireless extensions.

enp0s20u3  no wireless extensions.
```

Also I'm able to connect my computer to internet through tethering, if needed.

I thank you all guys in advance for taking care of me and my problem, looking forward your answer! Also I do apologize if the language sounds a bit odd, but I'm not a native English speaker!

EDIT:

OUTPUT of the command line `sudo apt-get install dkms broadcom-sta-dkms` after `sudo apt-get update`

```
Lettura elenco dei pacchetti... Fatto
Generazione albero delle dipendenze       
Lettura informazioni sullo stato... Fatto
dkms is already the newest version (2.2.0.3-2ubuntu11.3).
È stato impostato dkms per l'installazione manuale.
I seguenti pacchetti NUOVI saranno installati:
  broadcom-sta-dkms
0 aggiornati, 1 installati, 0 da rimuovere e 17 non aggiornati.
È necessario scaricare 2.204 kB di archivi.
Dopo quest'operazione, verranno occupati 14,5 MB di spazio su disco.
Continuare? [S/n] s
Scaricamento di:1 http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/multiverse amd64 broadcom-sta-dkms all 6.30.223.271-2 [2.204 kB]
Recuperati 2.204 kB in 17s (127 kB/s)                                                       
Selezionato il pacchetto broadcom-sta-dkms non precedentemente selezionato.
(Lettura del database... 190202 file e directory attualmente installati.)
Preparativi per estrarre .../broadcom-sta-dkms_6.30.223.271-2_all.deb...
Estrazione di broadcom-sta-dkms (6.30.223.271-2)...
Configurazione di broadcom-sta-dkms (6.30.223.271-2)...
Loading new broadcom-sta-6.30.223.271 DKMS files...
First Installation: checking all kernels...
Building only for 4.8.0-36-generic
Building initial module for 4.8.0-36-generic
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.8.0-36-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/broadcom-sta/6.30.223.271/build/make.log for more information.
```

I'm sorry for those italian strings, I can translate them if needed. Anyways, as can be seen, at the end it gives me the same error message it gave me before trying with Ndiswrapper.

Comment: You seem to have tried the hardest solution first: ndiswrapper...and it didn't work. Not a surprise. What other (easier) solutions have you tried?

Comment: Did you implement Jeremy31's solution?

Comment: What's the content of `/var/lib/dkms/broadcom-sta/6.30.223.271/build/make.log`?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers is a spurious duplicate because it doesn't actually contain instructions for the BCM43142 (though it may in the future).

Answer (score 1):

You need to download a newer version of broadcom-sta-dkms with the patches so it will build with a 4.8 kernel

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/multiverse/b/broadcom-sta/broadcom-sta-dkms_6.30.223.271-3_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i broadcom-sta-dkms_6.30.223.271-3_all.deb
```

Reboot